Markov Property - Equivalent Definitions
Hi I'm trying to show the following 2 definitions of the Markov property are equivalent. Everything I found online includes some general function but my question is more fundamental:
Given A a Borel subset of the state space, for all $t>s$

$\mathbb{P}(x_{t}\in A |\mathcal{F}_{s})=\mathbb{P}(x_{t}\in A |x_{s})$


$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{A}(x_{t})\mathbb{1}_{C}]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{P}(x_{t} \in A|x_{s})\mathbb{1}_{C}]$ for all $C \in \mathcal{F}_{s}$.

How do we show these are equivalent?

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

never mind i inserted 1 into rhs of 2 and used tower property
